# Efficiently reusing unwrapped Option variable based on a condition in Rust

Tags: rust

I have an `Option` variable `pb` in Rust that I need to use in multiple parts of my code. However, I don't want to repeat the unwrapping logic each time I access `pb` to obtain the unwrapped value, when I now once the variable `progress_var_on` is `true`, `pb` should have a value. Is there a clean and efficient way to unwrap `pb` once and use the unwrapped value throughout my code without cluttering it with repeated match statements?

Here is an example:

```rust
// ...

let pb = if progress_bar_on {
  // ...
  Some(tmp_pb)
} else {
  None
}

if progress_bar_on {
  pb.unwrap().update_var();
  pb.unwrap().set_val();
}

// more code
// ...

if progress_bar_on {
  pb.unwrap().set_val();
}

// more code
// ...

if progress_bar_on {
  pb.unwrap().update_var();
}
```

Something I just learn, and it feels cleaner is the next:

```rust
if let Some(pb) =
    progress_bar_on.then(|| pb.unwrap())
{
    pb.set_style(style_overall);
    pb.set_message("Copying files...");
    pb.set_length(src_n_files);
}
```

Is this the cleanest way? or there is a better way?
Any insights or suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Since `pb` is initialised based on `progress_bar_on` and will "keep sync with" that `bool`, I guess it's ok to use `if let` directly on `pb`: `if let Some(pb) = pb { /* do your jobs */ }`

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially converting the boolean `progress_bar_on` into an `Option`, so you should use the `Option`.

```rs
if let Some(pb) = pb {
    pb.update_var();
}
```

However, this is still not very clean and still has to do a check every time `pb` will be used. The robust way to is to make a trait.

```rs
trait ProgressBar: Default {
    fn update_var(&mut self);
    fn set_val(&mut self);
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct RealProgressBar {
    progress: u32,
}

impl ProgressBar for RealProgressBar {
    fn update_var(&mut self) {
        // Some real work
        self.progress += 1;
    }

    fn set_val(&mut self) {
        // Some real work
        self.progress = 0;
    }
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct DummyProgressBar;

// This does nothing when used as a progress bar
impl ProgressBar for DummyProgressBar {
    fn update_var(&mut self) {}
    fn set_val(&mut self) {}
}

// Public-facing function
pub fn do_operation(progress_bar_on: bool) {
    // Convert the runtime boolean into a compile-time trait impl
    if progress_bar_on {
        do_operation_progress::<RealProgressBar>()
    } else {
        do_operation_progress::<DummyProgressBar>()
    }
}

// Private function that has all the logic. It can unconditionally
// call methods on the progress bar.
fn do_operation_progress<P: ProgressBar>() {
    let mut pb = P::default();

    // some code

    pb.update_var();

    // some more code

    pb.set_val();
}
```

Comment: Nit: `_do_operation` should be `do_operation`. In rust, a leading underscore implies that an item isn't used, not that it's private, since we have a proper visibility system to take care of that.

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues That name is already used. I'll change it to something else.